# Number of permutations with several types of distinguishable objects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I want to know the general form of the answer to this example.

How many different arrangements are there of 4 objects, 2 of type 1 and 2 of type 2, where there are 20 objects of type I and 30 objects of type II? *All objects are distinguishable*.

I tired: $P_{2}^{20}P_{2}^{30} $, among other things, but it doesn't yield the answer. Is that because the cartesian product doesn't account for all the arrangements?

How could I count this **positively**, meaning, I don't want to subtract the other possible arrangements to get to this one? I understand how to do that much.

Sorry if it's a dumb question, help would be much appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the order matters: first your choose 4 objects (2 from each type) and then permute them, so that the expression is $$\binom {20}2\binom {30}24!. $$
If the order does not matter omit $4! $.

Comment: Thanks so much, I found out I had actually tried this but made a mistake on my calculator! I was confused as to why nothing worked haha. I rechecked thanks to you and that’s right! I had already forgotten after trying other things

Comment: You are welcome.